# Nexus 3 Site Deployment

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have a project which was deploying a maven-generated site to a nexus2 repository.  Here's my current configuration:

```
<distributionManagement>
<repository>
  <id>nexus-group</id>
  <url>http://[some_url]/repository/[repo]-releases/</url>
</repository>
<snapshotRepository>
  <id>nexus-group</id>
  <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
  <url>http://[some_url]/repository/[repo]-snapshots/</url>
</snapshotRepository>
<site>
  <id>nexus-group</id>
  <url>dav:http://[some_url]/repository/[repo]-site/[project]/latest/</url>
</site>
</distributionManagement>
```

I have recently updated to nexus3 and created a raw repository for deployment, but have encountered some issues.

1. It seems when creating Javadocs, a javascript file (script.js) is created in the /target/site/apidocs directory.  Why am I unable to upload this file into a raw repository?  This fails the build.
2. For every file which is uploaded I have a transfer error (even on the initial upload): **java.io.IOException: unable to create collection: http://[some_url]/repository, status code = 400**.  Is this my error or Nexus'?  Ultimately the upload is successful along with the build, assuming script.js isn't present.
3. In nexus2 content was conveniently grouped by artifactId which could be drilled-down to using the UI browser.  Am I deploying incorrectly or is this feature no longer available?  I haven't found anything to tell me otherwise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disabling the strict content type validation allows me to move past the script.js upload problem.

Comment: Also, removing [project]/latest/ from the site url eliminated the "unable to create collection" errors.

Comment: For the js file, can you pop over to https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS and file an issue? It seems odd to me that a javascript file wouldn't pass validation on a raw repo (these are hypothetically wide open).

Comment: Also, other than the last question it sounds like you are in business? Is that correct?

Comment: @DarthHater yes, in business... why do you ask?  Also, I'll enter an issue thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh, just like to make sure people are taken care of :) I work at Sonatype.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added correctly webdav-jackrabit to your maven-site-plugin configuration:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
          <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
          <version>2.12</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Yes.  The project has been deploying without any problems to a nexus 2 repository for some time now.

Comment: The deploy to repository is going via simply http(s) for the site it should be using WebDAV which is something different...I would also check first to using wagon-webdav to configure as an extension

Comment: the site has been deploying just excluding certain content, namely the script.js file.  The site url is listed as dav:http...  I was able to deploy the javascript file by lifting the content type restriction on the repository.